# WPF Datagrid Combobox binding issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I have the following code that does not update the datagrid after selection within a Combobox. No errors, just no update.

I suspect I need to link the DataGrid data with the Combobox data somehow to trigger the update but I am not exactly sure how.
BTW the equivalent does work with `List<string>` , just not `List<Model>`

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
The collection CodeCategories is a separate List with just  Code_Category and Code_Category_Id. I am using a separate ViewModel, to populate the DataGrid, which contains several fields including Code_Category_Id to be linked back to.

```
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="350" Header="CODE CATEGORY" HeaderTextWrapping="Wrap" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource mainHeader}">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CODE_CATEGORY, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CodeCategories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" SelectedValue="{Binding CODE_CATEGORY_ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="CODE_CATEGORY" SelectedValuePath="CODE_CATEGORY_ID">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: How is the ItemsSource of the Telerik DataGrid itself specified? Does it bind to the same collection named `CodeCategories` - also the same *instance* of it?

Comment: The collection CodeCategories is a separate List with just  Code_Category and Code_Category_Id. I am using a separate ViewModel, to populate the DataGrid, which contains several fields including Code_Category_Id to be linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why but this worked

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn  Width="350"  Header="CODE CATEGORY" HeaderTextWrapping="Wrap" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource mainHeader}" 
DataMemberBinding="{Binding CODE_CATEGORY_ID}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CodeCategories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
DisplayMemberPath="CODE_CATEGORY" 
SelectedValueMemberPath="CODE_CATEGORY_ID" />
```